# Building a string character by character

Tags: c, string, c99

I am consuming a character stream (unseekable) which contains separated strings: e.g. `abc|def|ghijkd` with the separator `|`. Hence when I am parsing a token, I keep adding the characters of the stream to a string until I find a pipe, and then I start a new string.

I don't want to copy around the string under construction each time I add a new character.

**What is the standard practice of building a string of a priori unknown length?**

What I am doing now is basically allocating a "block" of given size (say 256 chars) and copying there the characters from the stream. When the block is full I increment the block size (in steps of the initial block size), allocate a new block, copy the old block to the new position, free the old block, add characters to the end of the new block, etc, rinse and repeat. This appears a bit sledge-hammer to me.

Comment: Can you use std::string?  That would make it easy.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy This looks like C++ to me. Are you sure this is C?

Comment: `std::string` is not available in C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is essentially what [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) does, except that it will only copy if it's unable to enlarge the block.  Standard practice is to double the size of your block each time.  The exponential growth will limit the number of reallocations required.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into `realloc`. This sounds like that's what I am looking for.

Comment: I should have mentioned that in the worst case, doubling the block size can lead to your strings consuming almost twice as much memory as required.  If you're concerned about this, just do a final `realloc` when you complete the string, to resize the block down to the exact size you require.